# Background processing

Tags: ios

We are in the process of developing Minder app for obVus (https://www.obvus.me/) which focuses on developing user-friendly products to change behavior and condition healthy habits.

Minder app (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/minder/id1437980397) allows you to check in with how you are feeling throughout the day. Minder tracks healthy posture stats, wear time, steps, mindful minutes, heart rate, goal, and Me/Mo progress which are all visualized on our intuitive, user-friendly dashboard. Minder syncs to Apple Health to keep all your vital health data in one place.

We are using Apple Watch and Airpods as wearable devices to track postures. We would like to incorporate Airpod posture tracking when Minder app goes to background!

Our team did research and we found that Air pods automatically get disconnected when we put the app to background by its default behaviour. We are automatically reconnecting it when we launch the minder app to foreground.

There are only limited number of background execution modes our app can support that enable it to run when in the background, such as playing audio, receiving location updates, or processing scheduled tasks etc. Here is the apple reference doc for the background services that our iPhone, iPad, Apple Watch, and Apple TV apps require to continue executing in the background: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes
In the case of Apple Watch, this is possible since the minder app uses a workout session to track a user’s activity on Apple Watch but such mechanism is not available in AirPods

Can you please help us on this? Is there any mechanism to track user’s postures by using Aipods as sensors while the app goes on background . Can you please guide us so that we can incorporate Airpod posture tracking when our Minder app goes to background.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a `HKWorkoutSession` to keep your Watch app to continue executing code in the BACKGROUND (For Watch)
Or start a `Location Updating` that `allowBackgroundUpdate = true` (For both Watch & Phone)

**The biggest issue is High Power Consumption.**

Here are some tips that you can apply to save battery for Watch/Phone.

- When using `HKWorkoutSession`, start it and then pause it after 1 second to save battery.
- When using `CLLocationManager`, start it after set `distanceFilter = 3000`, `desiredAccuracy = 3000`. It is like you just wanna run app in Background not updating location. With long distance filter and low accuracy, battery consumption rate will be very low.
- Avoid running too many timer instances.
- Limit the I/O usage

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actually i am facing issue with Air-pod. I am getting gyro sensor data from air-pod. But if my app in background then gyro sensor data stop and when i will come to foreground then data coming. So i need to get gyro data in background.

Comment: @AnkitBhardwaj The issue of using CLLocationManager that AppStore Reviewer may ask you for a reason that why user needs to grant Location permission.

Comment: I am not using CLLocation manager, i have doubt about CMHeadphoneMotionManager

Comment: @AnkitBhardwaj I checked this one. It is like an Accelerometer updating but it doesn't keep your app running in the background. You do need a Background Audio or Background Location

Comment: If i will use location update then apple will not allow on Appstore. hey will ask reason.

Comment: @AnkitBhardwaj Yes, like what I said above, they will ask you to provide them a good reason why this app needs Location Service functioning.
Or you can use the Background Audio, run a mute audio file that has very long duration.

Comment: But if i will run mute audio for very long time then they will ask reason for mute audio?

Comment: @AnkitBhardwaj It doesn't affect much to users so you can start it. It doesn't need user permission to run audio, so you can freely start it. Change the audio file name to your Bundle Display Name or Product Name, which will help the user to know what is happening.

Comment: Is it possible with BGTaskScheduler?

Comment: @AnkitBhardwaj No, it is like a cron-job, scheduler. System will wake the app to run in the background (mode) to execute codes every x seconds.
But the system will limit your app's background time.